# Extracting substrings at specified positions

Tags: python

How to extract substrings  from a string at specified positions
For e.g.: ‘ABCDEFGHIJKLM’. I have To extract the substring from  3 to 6 and 8 to 10.

Required output: DEFG, IJK

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Here you go

```
myString = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'
first = myString[3:7] # => DEFG
second = myString[8:11] # => IJK
```

In the slicing syntax, the first number is inclusive and the second is excluded.

You can read more about String slicing from [python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Answer (score 3):

Look into Python's concept called sequence slicing!

Answer (score 3):

```
a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLM"
print a[3:7], a[8:11]
```

--> DEFG IJK

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'
print s[3:7]
print s[8:11]
```

Comment: Why `7` and `11` rather than `8` and `10`? What is that syntax? Please explain and provide references.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'[3:7]
'DEFG'
>>> 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'[8:11]
'IJK'
```

You might want to read a [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) or beginners book.

Answer (score 0):

In alternative you can use operator.itemgetter:

```
>>> import operator
>>> s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLM'
>>> f = operator.itemgetter(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
>>> f(s)
('D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L')
```

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(slice(3, 7), slice(8, 11))('ABCDEFGHIJKLM') == ('DEFG', 'IJK')`